# Java EE 6 JPA 2.0 provider for DB2/400?

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, ibm-midrange

For Java EE development in an IBM iSeries (aka AS/400) environment, I would like to use JPA 2.0. Is there a JPA 2.0 provider with support for DB2/400 databases?

Update: target deployment environment will be JBoss AS 6 and 7.

Comment: Q: Are you using IBM RAD Developer as your J2EE IDE?  ALSO: check out this link:  http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS210-129

Comment: My main development environment is NetBeans 7.1 / GlassFish 3.1 (or Eclipse)

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something from your questions, but as long as you pull in a compatible driver you should be able to use any of the existing JPA 2.0 implementations (EclipseLink, Hibernate).

Comment: @Perception this week I saw a JPA configuration file which included a Hibernate-specific configuration of the 'database dialect' for DB2. But I understand that it should be database independent if there is a compliant JDBC driver

Comment: @mjn - The specification for persistence units allows you to specify driver and JPA provider specific properties. It is in this file that you will be 'telling' your JPA provider how to link up with your database (after making the driver available of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. With your target environment (JBoss AS 6 and 7) you already have JPA 2.0 capable Hibernate runtime, so I assume that Hibernate is the persistence provider you want to use.

- If you do not have JDBC driver yet, find one matching to DB2 version:
  [drivers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866)
- If you use Hibernate, then dialect is [org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/DB2Dialect.html). If you plan to use some other persistence provider, probably you can find information about dialect from the documentation.

Opposite to to what you present in your comment, at least Hibernate does not choose right dialect based to driver. There is no one-to-one mapping between driver and dialect. For example with MySQL dialect depends about table type (innoDb/MyISAM) and version of MySQL, and all of them can be used with same version of Connector/J.

Comment: Note:  You will need Journalling active for all tables.  JPA expects COMMIT/ROLLBACK.  The DB2/400 JDBC type 4 driver is in jt400.jar.